# Stop core data from syncing with iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

Hy everyone,

I am making an app that utilises core data and iCloud to sync user file across his devices, I managed to implement the core data syncing, and now I want to add an switch to let the user turn on and off the iCloud sync, I am trying to use the next code approach to stop the core data sqlite database file from sync:

```
- (void)migrateiCloudStoreToLocalStore:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]];

}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"iCloudOn"]) {
        NSLog(@"nsuserdefaults iCloud value is on");
    }

    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"iCloudOn"]]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

I also tied to pass the url as so:

```
NSString *dataFileName = @"APP.sqlite";
 NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
```

but the app stopped in the assert.

And this is my persistent Store Coordinator inside AppDelegate.m:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if((_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

    // Set up iCloud in another thread:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"APPID";

        // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
        NSString *dataFileName = @"APPNAME.sqlite";

        // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

        NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
        NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
        NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

        if (iCloud) {

            NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

            NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

            NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
            NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
            NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
            NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                NSError *fileSystemError;
                [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                        attributes:nil
                                             error:&fileSystemError];
                if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                }
            }

            NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

            NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

            options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
            [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

            [psc performBlockAndWait:^{
                [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                  configuration:nil
                                            URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                        options:options
                                          error:nil];
            }];

        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");
            options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
            [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

            [psc performBlockAndWait:^{
                [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                  configuration:nil
                                            URL:localStore
                                        options:options
                                          error:nil];

            }];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:nil userInfo:nil];
        });
    });

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;

}
```

If anyone know a way around this I will much appreciate it.

Comment: You can't just turn iCloud sync on and off.  You have to migrate the store to and from iCloud and this will affect other devices.  There are APIs for doing this, look at `migratePersistentStore:toURL:withOptions` as a start. Or check here for sample apps that might help http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/